Show $f(f(x))-x$ is monotonically decreasing on $(\frac 1{\sqrt{2}} , 1)$
Let $f(x)=x+\frac 1x -\sqrt{2} ,\space x>0$ .
Then show that $f(f(x))-x$ is monotonically decreasing on $(\frac 1{\sqrt{2}} , 1)$
Seems a preety trivial question but have been trying for long without success.
1st Attempt : We have
$f'(x)=\big( 1-\frac 1{x^2} \big)<0 , \forall x \in (0,1)  $
Now ,
$\frac d{dx}(f(f(x))-x)=\frac d{dx} \big( f(x) +\frac 1{f(x)} -\sqrt{2}-x \big) $
$= f'(x)\big( 1-\frac 1{f^2(x)}\big)-1   $
So I want $f^2(x) > 1$ which gives
$\big(x +\frac 1x \big)> \sqrt{2} +1      \space...(*)$
Taking equality in $(*)$ and solving the quadratic  for $x$ , we get a rubbish expression for $x$
Attempt 2: I tried to simply show $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}} <x <y <1 \implies f(f(x))-x> f(f(y))-y $
But this was again unsuccessful.
The graph can prove this result however it's apparently not so clear analytically .
Hints please.

Expanding on the OP's first attempt.
Let $f(x):=x+\frac{1}{x}-\sqrt{2}.$ Show $g(x):=f(f(x))-x$ is decreasing on $\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right)$.
Since $f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}$ it follows that
\begin{align*}
g'(x)&=f'(f(x))f'(x)-1  \\
&= \left(1-\frac{1}{f(x)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-1 \\
&= \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{f(x)^2}-\frac{1}{f(x)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}
\end{align*}
Multiplying by $x^2 f(x)^2$ shows $g'(x)<0$ is equivalent to $1-x^2-f(x)^2<0.$ Let $h(x):=f(x)^2+x^2-1.$ It is sufficient to show $h(x)>0$ on $\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right).$
Nów $h\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=0,$ so it is sufficient to show $h'(x)>0$ on $\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right).$ Now
$$h'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)+2x$$ So
$h'\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=2f\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)f'\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+2\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=2\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-2)+2\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=0.$ So it is sufficient to show $h''(x)>0$ on $\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right).$
Will this ever end?
Yes. $$h''(x)=2f(x)f''(x)+2\left(f'(x)\right)^2+2$$
is a sum of three non-negative terms.
In fact, $f''(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}>0$ when $0<x$. And $f'(x)<0$ when $0<x<1$ so  $f$ is decreasing on $(0,1)$ and $f(x)>f\left(1\right)=2-\sqrt{2}>0$  when $0<x<1.$

Hint:
$g(x) = f(f(x))-x=\frac 1x+\frac {1}{x+1/x-\sqrt{2}}+\text{const.}$
Edit:
$g'(x) = -\frac{(x+1/x-\sqrt{2})^2+x^2-1}{x^2 (x+1/x-\sqrt{2})^2}~.$
The denominator is positive and the numerator is negative.

In RHS , the first function is decreasing and positive  and the denominator function in second term is decreasing on $(0,1)$ and positive so it's reciprocal is increasing and positive. The addition of a decreasing and an increasing function may be anything .I am not sure what to conclude more out of this . Please clarify more , sir.

Explained in the post now

So it means the function is decreasing on all $\mathbb{R}_+ $?

Indeed, you can also check by plotting, e.g., on https://www.desmos.com/calculator
